# When installing php on Ubuntu/Debian, how do I choose the development php.ini

Tags: php, ubuntu, installation, debian

I believe there is a php.ini with settings optimized for development. How can I install that one the easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on KRONWALLED's answer, this is what to enter in the shell

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-development /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
sudo cp /usr/lib/php/7.0/php.ini-development /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
```

Comment: Thats what I would do too. I meant if some dpkg guru knows a way how to say something like this `dpkg-reconfigure php development` and the dev ini magically appears ;)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the package is a file called `php.ini-development`. Just copy it over into the php config directory (/etc/php5 if default)

Edit: Don't forget to rename it to php.ini ;)

Comment: I was wondering if there is some kein of dpkg-configure option for that to make it even more idiot proof...

Comment: I don't think so but lets wait if someone else knows a way to do it.